# Beginner Question, working with JSF using Ajax/CSS

Tags: jsf

i have to make a GUI using JSF, Ajax and CSS working with Apache Database. Im new to this so can someone suggest me any any suitable framework to start with?

Comment: You have to make a webapplication using JSF ? Then use the `JSF` framework.

Comment: Have a look http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-09-2006/jw-0911-jsf.html?page=1

Answer (score 0):

You can get some knowledge about JSF in the following site

http://www.coreservlets.com/JSF-Tutorial/jsf2/

It will be helpful for your development activity